# When an entry box is present, a button does not show up

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have been doing some work in python and have came across Tkinter which is very useful for my project. I was in the process of making a screen where there is a button and a text entry box however when the text entry box is present, no button shows up. However when I remove the entry box, I can see the button.

Here is the part of the script I've been working on:

Hi, I have been doing some work in python and have came across Tkinter which is very useful for my project. I was in the process of making a screen where there is a button and a text entry box however when the text entry box is present, no button shows up. However when I remove the entry box, I can see the button.

```
from tkinter import *

def submit1():
    print("working");

def password1():
    passwordbox= Tk()
    passwordbox.title("Password Verification")
    passwordbox.configure(background="white")
    passwordbox.geometry("1000x1000")


    box1 = Entry(passwordbox, width=200, bg="gray")
    box1.grid(row=2000, column=10, sticky=W)

    submit = Button(passwordbox, text="Submit", width=20, height=5, 
bg="black", fg="white", command=submit1)
    submit.grid(row=1000, column=15, sticky=W);

password1()
```

The text box should show to entry box and the button however it only shows the button

If the entry box code was # out, the button will work

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: The Entry is over 1000 pixels wide, so it pushes the Button off the right side of the window.  Either reduce the size of the Entry (are you really expecting the user to enter a 200 character password???), or stop specifying a size for the window when that size is insufficient to hold the contents.  Also, you seem to misunderstand what the row and column options to `.grid()` mean - with a total of two widgets, it's utterly pointless for either of those numbers to be greater than two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a line `passwordbox.mainloop()` at the end of password1 definition. Also you need to specify row and column of the grid properly.

Set Entry box to row 0 and column 0
Set Submit button to row 1 and column 0

```
from tkinter import *

def submit1():
    print("working");

def password1():
    passwordbox= Tk()
    passwordbox.title("Password Verification")
    passwordbox.configure(background="white")
    passwordbox.geometry("1000x1000")


    box1 = Entry(passwordbox, width=200, bg="gray")
    box1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

    submit = Button(passwordbox, text="Submit", width=20, height=5, 
bg="black", fg="white", command=submit1)
    submit.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W);
    passwordbox.mainloop()

password1()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rishabh!